# What is the meaning of "by design" phrase in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

Came across this in NY Times:

"Pete Souza’s intimate backstage portraits of the Obama West Wing are missing one person by design, he said."

what did the author mean by "by design"????

Comment: "by design" = "on purpose" - it was designed that way. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20design

Answer (score 1):

"By design" literally means "intentionally" or "on purpose".

It's usually used when something might appear to be a mistake or omission, but was actually intended.

A common example is that traditionally, Persian carpets contain some flaw in the pattern. This isn't due to the incompetence of the makers, but to the belief that it's an affront to God to make something perfect, so they purposefully introduce a flaw to assert their status as lower than God. In this case, the flaw in the carpet pattern is by design.

From your example sentence, because of "by design", I can understand that there's someone missing from Souza's portraits who I should expect to be there, and that it was part of Souza's plan.

Answer (score 0):

"Design" here is a synonym for "intent". The phrase "by design" therefore means "deliberate" or "deliberately".